# Unity building project stuck at "3/11 4 jobs"

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, loading, terrain

[image]

For the last couple of weeks i have had some issues with unity. I have tried to reinstall it, but it still does some weird stuff. As you can see in the screenshot below Building scene 0: SWAT is stuck at 3/11 Create System | 4 jobs
and i get 999+ errors and warnings. I have asked this question on the Unity forum but i didn't get an answer so please help. Thanks you!

Comment: Searching around, other people who had this problem usually seemed to be doing lighting builds (lightmaps, global illumination, etc.). You might check GI cache settings (`Edit` > `Preferences` > `GI Cache`), either cache size or just clearing the cache.

Comment: @rutter Thank you very much. It helped and i am now error free!